# VB.Net Calculator Wrong Value

Tags: .net, vb.net, console-application

I write a code on VB.Net that ask a user to input two numbers and the console program will output the addition of the two numbers. but I  don't know why, when I run the program, the return value of numbers that a entered and the answer are completely wrong.

this is the code:

Module Module1

```
Sub Main()
    Dim a As Integer = 0
    Dim b As Integer = 0
    Dim c As Integer = 0
    Console.Write("Write a number: ")
    a = Console.Read()
    Console.ReadLine()
    Console.Write("Write the second number:")
    b = Console.Read()
    c = a + b
    Console.ReadLine()
    Console.Write("Answer:")
    Console.WriteLine(a & "+" & b & "=" & c)
    Console.Read()
End Sub
```

End Module

So when I run the program this is what happen:

Write a number: 5
Write the second number: 3
Answer: 53+51=104

As you can see the return value are completely wrong, I try with many other numbers but the return value are still wrong and I am a little confuse. If you Gentleman can help me it gonna be great thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`Console.Read()` returns an integer that corresponds to the character code of the entered character.  You are assuming that the data you enter is being interpreted as a decimal number literal, but this is incorrect.

What you actually want to set `a` and `b` equal to is:

`Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToChar(Console.Read()).ToString())`

Comment: Thanks for the syntax fix, forgot that Console.Read returns an Int.

Comment: I changed the line to this: a = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToChar(Console.Read())) and b = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToChar(Console.Read())), but the results are still the same.

Comment: In visual studio, put a breakpoint after the 'a = ...' line; then tell us what the value of a is, according to the watch window or even if you just put the mouse pointer over the a variable, you should get a tooltip showing you its value.

Comment: @PhilippeKatshianga , Please see the updated syntax.  I made an error in my original post.  (Converting a character to an integer yields the character's underlying integer value which is what you had originally, but the converting the single character string representation of that character to an integer yields the integer value of the representative symbol).  I have tested this

Comment: @RussC, In case you're interested see the update and my last comment

Comment: Console.Read returns a Char so it makes no sense to convert a Char to a Char and then ToString?  And what if the user wants to enter a number with multiple digits (e. g. 25)?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway, You are mistaken about `Console.Read`.  See [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read.aspx).  In response to your second question, you can obtain a string using [Console.ReadLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline), but it requires the user to press Enter

Comment: @smartcaveman - Thanks for pointing that out.  I thought it returned Char which is why I found it odd to convert it to Char again!  The documentation at the link you gave for Read also says that you must press Enter which seems odd to me as well.

Comment: @Phillipe Katshianga, you're welcome.  You can mark an answer as selected by clicking the check to the left of the answer and making it green

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing up types in your

```
Console.WriteLine(a & "+" & b & "=" & c)
```

Line.

53 is the numeric representation of the string "5" and 51 is the same for "3".

If you were to change your input to 5 and 5; it'd print.

53+53=106

As a fun experiment, see what happens when you press the letter 'a' instead of a number.

Edit :

Please see Smartcavemans answer for the right syntax to solve your problem.

Comment: Umm possibly; can you edit that into your question please ? my dyslexia makes it very hard to read code like that :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim a As Integer = 0
    Dim b As Integer = 0
    Dim c As Integer = 0

    Console.Write("Write a number: ")
    a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())

    Console.Write("Write the second number:")
    b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())

    c = a + b

    Console.Write("Answer:")
    Console.WriteLine("{0} + {1} = {2}", a, b, c)

    Console.ReadLine
End Sub
```

NOTE:  If you enter anything that is not a valid integer, this will likely throw an exception.

Comment: I tryed your code, it working but it doesn't show the comments (Write a number, write the second number, Answer), what the use of comments if doesn't showing up. 

If I wanted to have no comments I would have write this code :

 Sub Main()
        Dim a As Integer = 0
        Dim b As Integer = 0
        a = Console.ReadLine()
        b = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine(a + b)
        Console.Read()

    End Sub

Comment: It works for me because I tested it before I posted it.  Where are you placing the code?  What type of project are you running?  Windows Forms?  Console?  Console.Writeline will only work in a Console application.

Comment: I am running on Windows console.

Comment: Nevermind, I retry it and it worked perfectly just as I planed, Thank you, But I have a question: what is the use of Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()), if I already declared it as an integer?

Comment: @PhilippeKatshianga: Console.ReadLine() returns a string so you must convert it to Integer in order to perform calculations.  You should turn Option Strict On in your project properties to help with things like this.

Comment: sorry I am back, can you just explain me what you did in this last line please ' Console.WriteLine("{0} + {1} = {2}", a, b, c)' because I think this line it  special :)

Comment: @PhilippeKatshianga - That just uses string format specifiers.  The {0}, {1} and {2} are place holders corresponding to the variables in the list (a, b and c).  See this link:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx